# Account Kit: Error verifying the token in the 'access_token'

Tags: python, facebook, api, http, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve an access token for an authentication code. I'm using the following format:

GET https://graph.accountkit.com/v1.0/access_token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=AUTH_CODE&access_token=AA|APP_ID|APP_SECRET

where AUTH_CODE, APP_ID, and APP_SECRET are their respective values. Here is the python I use to assemble this URL:

```
url = 'https://graph.accountkit.com/v1.0/access_token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=' + authcode + '&access_token=AA|' + facebook_app_id + '|' + facebook_app_secret
```

But I keep getting the following error:

`{
    error: {
        message: "Error verifying the token in the 'access_token'",
        type: "OAuthException",
        code: 190,
        fbtrace_id: "GNhScPPp22t"
    }
}`

I tried googling the fbtrace_id but literally nothing came up. And I don't understand why it's saying it can't verify the token in "access_token", I do *exactly* what their documentation says to do.

Anyone have an idea of where my issue may be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They use a different app secret for AccountKit versus the rest of Facebook.

Comment: I noticed this, doc should specify "use AccountKitt app secret" instead of "use app secret"

Answer (score 1):

The error is Because of the Facebook App Configuration.

I followed this tutorial regarding [accountkit setup](http://mycodde.blogspot.com/2016/10/facebook-accountkit-login-using-mobile.html)

It shows the solution as below

[image]

Alternatively create an Test app under your Main app and you can play with Configuration (It wont affect production)

Answer (score 0):

Use following app secret at server:

[ PRODUCTS -> Account Kit -> Settings -> Account Kit App Secret ]